# How to configure different interfaces/contexts with different SSL configurations for SMTP, external JSON API and MySQL JDBC in Java Tomcat (Liferay)?

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

We use the Liferay application in our environment. This is a Java CMS software, that we have deployed with Tomcat 9. In our application need to use the following interfaces:

- We send emails over an external SMTP mail gateway over SSL. That gateway has a "special" SSL certificate chain.
- We have also an external JSON API that requires SSL and also certificate authentication! That interface has its own "special" SSL certificate chain.
- And we also use a managed MySQL DB instance and there is also a requirement, that this DB has to be connected over SSL

Now, to be able to use the SSL Mail Gateway and the external JSON API over SSL with certificate authentication, following configuration has been done:

1. We created a Java KeyStore file with the certificate chain for the SMTP Mailgateway and the certificate chain for the external JSON API
2. We configured this KeyStore file as Java start parameters into the [TOMCAT]/bin/setenv.sh script - like this:

```
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/my/certificate.store
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=PASSW0RD!
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/my/certificate.store
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=PASSW0RD!
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12
```

(We need to use the certificate store file as KeyStore AND TrustStore as we need to be able to establish an SSL connection to the external SMTP mail gateway and the extrenal JSON API and the JSON API requires an authentication over an SSL certificate. So our application needs to present a valid certificate as well).

Now the issue! If we have the described SSL configuration ON, we are not able to connect to our MySQL DB over SSL. Only this JDBC URL works:

```
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://[MYSQL_IP]:3306/lportal?characterEncoding=UTF-8&dontTrackOpenResources=true&holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true&useFastDateParsing=false&useUnicode=true&sslMode=DISABLED
```

If we remove the -Djavax.net.ssl.* parameters from the setenv.sh, we can connect to our DB over SSL like this:

```
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://[MYSQL_IP]:3306/lportal?characterEncoding=UTF-8&dontTrackOpenResources=true&holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true&useFastDateParsing=false&useUnicode=true&sslMode=REQUIRED&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

And yes, we have also tried to put the ca-bundle.pem from the managed MySQL database into our certificate store!

EVERY other configuration results in:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure__The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

AND

```
Bad Handshake
```

So SSL over JDBC works ONLY if we don't put the -Djavax.net.ssl.* parameters into the setenv.sh. Even if the ca-bundle.pem from the managed MySQL database is in the same KeyStore/TrustStore then SSL over JDBC will not work! EVER! I have tried a LOT to get that running, but it just doesn't work. I have used also different MySQL Connector/J driver versions.

Is it possible to get the JDBC URL somehow to completely ignore the -Djavax.net.ssl.* parameters in the setenv.sh?

Or is there a some other way to get SMTP over SSL, API over SSL and JDBC over SSL all-in-one? All interfaces use different certificate chains however.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: The `javax.net.ssl.*` parameters are used to configure the default [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html). You should modify your application to use different contexts for JDBC and mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my issue! The solution was to move the JDBC SQL connection configuration into a JNDI data source.

In the above configuration the JDBC config was in the Java.properties config file like this:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1:3306/lportal?characterEncoding=UTF-8&dontTrackOpenResources=true&holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true&useFastDateParsing=false&useUnicode=true&sslMode=DISABLED
jdbc.default.username=mysqluser
jdbc.default.password=PASSW0RD
```

Now I have moved the JDBC configuration into a Tomcat JNDI data source, so instead of the shown JDBC properties I have now only this line there:

```
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
```

In the [TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/context.xml I have added this additional line:

```
<Context>
...
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/LiferayPool" global="jdbc/LiferayPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

...
</Context>
```

I have created an extra Java key store for my SQL server CA certificate. This will be used in the JNDI config in the next step.

And in the [TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/server.xml I have my JNDI data source config:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
...
    <Resource name="jdbc/LiferayPool"
               auth="Container"
               description="Portal DB Connection"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
               driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1:3306/lportal?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;dontTrackOpenResources=true&amp;holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true&amp;useFastDateParsing=false&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;sslMode=VERIFY_CA&amp;clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:///path/to/my.keystore&amp;clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=PASSW0RD&amp;clientCertificateKeyStoreType=PKCS12&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:///path/to/my.keystore&amp;trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=PASSW0RD&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreType=PKCS12&amp;enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&amp;autoReconnect=true"
               username="mysqluser"
               password="PASSW0RD"
               maxActive="20"
               maxIdle="5"
               maxWait="10000" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

And now I have an SSL connection with my database and my SMTP and my JSON API with different SSL configurations and all this is now working fine together!

```
mysql> SELECT sbt.variable_value AS tls_version,  t2.variable_value AS cipher,                processlist_user AS user, processlist_host AS host         FROM performance_schema.status_by_thread  AS sbt         JOIN performance_schema.threads AS t ON t.thread_id = sbt.thread_id         JOIN performance_schema.status_by_thread AS t2 ON t2.thread_id = t.thread_id        WHERE sbt.variable_name = 'Ssl_version' and t2.variable_name = 'Ssl_cipher' ORDER BY tls_version, 4;
+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| tls_version | cipher                      | user         | host         |
+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| TLSv1.2     | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 | mysqluser    | 10.0.0.101   |
```

I hope this helps someone with the same issues...